# Endless Recycleview focus at top when pagination call android

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview, endlessscroll

Hello friends i m new in android and i want to integrate endless recycleview inmy application so below is my code

```
public class ActivityProdcutListWithMulipleView extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
Toolbar mToolbar;
PostParseGet mPostParseGet;
AllMethods mAllMethods;
GetProductListing mGetProductListing;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
int page = 1;
int total=0;
int totalFeature=0;
int totalbanner=0;
ProductAdapter mProductAdapter;
ImageView mImageViewBack;
ArrayList<GetProductListing.ListingBlock> mListingBlocks;
ArrayList<GetProductListing.ListingBlock> mListingBlocksFeature;
ArrayList<GetProductListing.ListingBlock> mListingBlocksBanner;

ArrayList<OrderItemDemo> mOrderItemDemos = new ArrayList<OrderItemDemo>();
GridLayoutManager mLayoutManagerGrid;
DifferentRowAdapter adapter;
private Handler handler;
ArrayList<GetProductListing.ListingBlock> adapterData;
public static Activity mActivity;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_product_list);
    mListingBlocks = new ArrayList<>();
    mActivity = this;
    mListingBlocksFeature = new ArrayList<>();
    mListingBlocksBanner = new ArrayList<>();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mImageViewBack = (ImageView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.imgBack);
    WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.clear();
    mPostParseGet = new PostParseGet(ActivityProdcutListWithMulipleView.this);
    mAllMethods = new AllMethods(ActivityProdcutListWithMulipleView.this);
    mGetProductListing = new GetProductListing();
    mLayoutManagerGrid = new GridLayoutManager(ActivityProdcutListWithMulipleView.this, 2);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ActivityProdcutListWithMulipleView.this);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagerGrid);
    handler = new Handler();
    adapterData = new ArrayList<>();


    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerGridOnScrollListener(mLayoutManagerGrid) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            if (WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.size() < total) {

                page++;
                new getProductData(false).execute();
            }
        }
    });

    adapter = new DifferentRowAdapter(mOrderItemDemos);
     mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    mLayoutManagerGrid.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return adapter.getItemViewType(position) == OrderItemDemo.BANNER_TYPE ? 2 : 1;
        }
    });

    if (mAllMethods.check_Internet() == true) {
        new getProductData(true).execute();
    } else {
        mAllMethods.ShowDialog(ActivityProdcutListWithMulipleView.this, "", getString(R.string.net_not_available), "OK");
    }
    mImageViewBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}


public static class DifferentRowAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    boolean isLoading = false, isMoreDataAvailable = true;
    private List<OrderItemDemo> mList;
    OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener;


    public DifferentRowAdapter(List<OrderItemDemo> list) {
        this.mList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;

        switch (viewType) {
            case OrderItemDemo.NORMAL_TYPE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_list_file, parent, false);
                return new ProductListRow(view);
            case OrderItemDemo.FEATURE_TYPE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_list_feature_file, parent, false);
                return new ProductListRow(view);
            case OrderItemDemo.BANNER_TYPE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_list_file, parent, false);
                return new ProductListRow(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(position>=getItemCount()-1 && isMoreDataAvailable && !isLoading && loadMoreListener!=null){
            isLoading = true;
            loadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
        }

        final OrderItemDemo object = mList.get(position);
        if (object != null) {
            switch (object.getmType()) {
                case OrderItemDemo.NORMAL_TYPE:
                    ((ProductListRow) holder).name.setText(object.getId()+" "+ object.getTitle());
                    ((ProductListRow) holder).price.setText(object.getType());

                    Picasso.with(mActivity)
                            .load(object.getImage())
                            .into(((ProductListRow) holder).mImageViewProduct);
                    ((ProductListRow) holder).mImageViewBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ((ProductListRow) holder).mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case OrderItemDemo.FEATURE_TYPE:
                    ((ProductListRow) holder).name.setText(object.getId()+" "+object.getTitle());
                    ((ProductListRow) holder).price.setText(object.getType());
                    ((ProductListRow) holder).mImageViewBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ((ProductListRow) holder).mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Picasso.with(mActivity)
                            .load(object.getImage())
                            .into(((ProductListRow) holder).mImageViewProduct);
                    break;
                case OrderItemDemo.BANNER_TYPE:
                    ((ProductListRow) holder).price.setText(object.getType());
                    ((ProductListRow) holder).mImageViewBanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((ProductListRow) holder).mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    public void setMoreDataAvailable(boolean moreDataAvailable) {
        isMoreDataAvailable = moreDataAvailable;
    }


    public void notifyDataChanged(){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        isLoading = false;
    }


    interface OnLoadMoreListener{
        void onLoadMore();
    }

    public void setLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener) {
        this.loadMoreListener = loadMoreListener;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mList == null)
            return 0;
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mList != null) {
            OrderItemDemo object = mList.get(position);
            if (object != null) {
                return object.getmType();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }


}

public abstract class EndlessRecyclerGridOnScrollListener extends
        RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    public String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class
            .getSimpleName();
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    private int current_page = 1;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerGridOnScrollListener(
            GridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        visibleThreshold = total;
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading
                && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached
            // Do something
            current_page++;
            onLoadMore(current_page);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
}


public class getProductData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    boolean showLoading;

    public getProductData(boolean showLoading) {
        this.showLoading = showLoading;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (showLoading == true) {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ActivityProdcutListWithMulipleView.this, "", "Loading..");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        mGetProductListing = (GetProductListing) mPostParseGet.getTopSearchData(mGetProductListing, page);
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (showLoading == true) {
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        if (mGetProductListing != null) {
            try {
                total = Integer.parseInt(mGetProductListing.getListing().getTotal());
                if (mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().size() > 0) {
                    mListingBlocks = getProductBlock();
                    Log.e("FeatureSize",String.valueOf(mListingBlocksFeature.size()));
                    Log.e("BannerSize",String.valueOf(mListingBlocksBanner.size()));

                    for (int i = 0; i < WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.size(); i++) {

                        if (WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("product")) {
                            mOrderItemDemos.add(new OrderItemDemo(WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getId(), WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getTitle(), WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getType(), WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getMedium_image(), OrderItemDemo.NORMAL_TYPE));
                        } else if (WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("featured")) {
                            mOrderItemDemos.add(new OrderItemDemo(WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getId(), WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getTitle(), WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getType(), WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getMedium_image(), OrderItemDemo.FEATURE_TYPE));
                        } else {
                            mOrderItemDemos.add(new OrderItemDemo(WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getId(), WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getTitle(), WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getType(), WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.get(i).getMedium_image(), OrderItemDemo.BANNER_TYPE));
                        }
                    }

                    adapter = new DifferentRowAdapter(mOrderItemDemos);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}

/*Get Product data  */
public ArrayList<GetProductListing.ListingBlock> getProductBlock() {
    ArrayList<GetProductListing.ListingBlock> mArrayListParserLog = new ArrayList<GetProductListing.ListingBlock>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().size(); i++) {


            GetProductListing.ListingBlock mParserLog = new GetProductListing.ListingBlock();
            mParserLog.setId(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getId());
            mParserLog.setType(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getType());
            mParserLog.setTitle(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getTitle());
            mParserLog.setDiscountSale(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getDiscountSale());
            mParserLog.setDiscountSelling(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getDiscountSelling());
            mParserLog.setPrice(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getPrice());
            mParserLog.setAupc(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getAupc());
            mParserLog.setSale_end(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getSale_end());
            mParserLog.setSale_start(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getSale_start());
            mParserLog.setSelling_price(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getSelling_price());
            mParserLog.setProduct_rating(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getProduct_rating());
            mParserLog.setSlug(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getSlug());
            mParserLog.setSold_out(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getSold_out());
            mParserLog.setImage(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getImage());
            mParserLog.setSku_id(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getSku_id());
            mParserLog.setMedium_image(mGetProductListing.getListing().getData().get(i).getMedium_image());
            mArrayListParserLog.add(mParserLog);
            WebAPIApplication.mArrayListingAllProductBlocks.add(mParserLog);



    }
    return mArrayListParserLog;
  }



}
```

When i call above code and call pagination at that time it will focus at top every time any idea how can solve this? your all suggestions are appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
               adapter = new DifferentRowAdapter(mOrderItemDemos);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Don't create a new adapter.  Change your adapter so that it can handle new items being added to it, then call notifyDataSetChanged on it.  By setting a new adapter, the recycler view loses its place and starts from the top.

Comment: thanks for reply but can you put demo code what you say so i can test it